# Why does ADO NET Source Show incorrect string data types by default?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and I created a simple Data Flow task.  The ADO NET Source shows all my varchar columns in ADO NET Source Output -> Output columns as Unicode string [DT_WSTR].  This is incorrect.  The table in Sql Server uses only varchar columns.  I tried to add a Data Conversion transformation, but I still get errors about converting unicode strings.  Why is SSIS reading my table schema incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DT_WSTR is an [SSIS datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx) which I think SSIS covert's to if working on it. Though I don't know why it is in this case.

My recommendation would be to try using the OLEDB source and destination - they seem to have much more power and flexibility in SSIS.

Comment: I'm not sure why ADO.Net is so poor - I know it is managed code, so I assume it is some sort of façade over some lower level stuff.

Comment: Gosh ADO.NET is so poor.